# Grub can't start windows

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, grub, elementaryos

I have got a Mi notebook air. Windows was installed in UEFI mode, but linux installed in Legacy. now i can boot windows only via UEFI , and linux only via legacy. grub detecting windows, but can't boot.

(elementary os, windows 10 and gnu grub)

Answer (score 0):

In Windows the boot method is determined by hard disk's partitioning scheme.

- On GPT disks, Windows will only boot with UEFI
- On MBR disks, Windows will only boot with CSM/BIOS aka. legacy

This means that your disk is GPT and you can't boot Windows using CSM.

Easy solutions:

- Configure UEFI to allow UEFI booting and CSM booting simultaneously (may not be available in your UEFI)
- Reinstall Linux in UEFI mode

Not-so-easy solutions:

- Install GRUB in UEFI mode. This will make Linux bootable without CSM.

  Requires quite a lot of tinkering. You have to install GRUB to ESP (EFI System Partition), add it to UEFI boot list, boot into Linux in UEFI mode and configure it to always install updates to GRUB in UEFI mode. If I recall correctly you can't do that when booting with CSM because `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` doesn't exist.
- Repartition hard disk with MBR scheme and fix Windows to work with it.

  Requires **a lot** of tinkering and cautiousness. Changing partitioning scheme will nullify all your partitions, you'll have to make backups in advance and restore them afterwards. Windows may be fussy about switching to MBR and most likely it won't boot. In the best-case scenario running "automatic repair" from Windows installation media will suffice, otherwise you'll have to fix BCD (Boot Configuration Data) manually.